# Safe usage of objects

Tags: java, oop

I want to write some code where it is possible to switch between two modes within one object.

- MODE to read:    userMode
- MODE to read+write:  adminMode
- userMode should only be able to read my getter methods.
- adminMode should be able to call setter and getter methods.

Some additional infos:

- Objects become provided in read-only mode
- The action unlock should switch to read+write mode.

---

## Important

The correct usage of a Object(depending on the mode) should be checked by the compiler at compile time, i.e. NOT by a checking a flag.

---

I have tried very hard, but I wasn't able to implement my project WITHOUT a boolean flag, which is in the task, so please show me how to...

Here my code with witch I am not satisfied:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    private boolean isAdmin;
    /*
     * ...
     */

    public Person(String name, double salary, boolean isAdmin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;

    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        if (isAdmin) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }

    }

    public void enableAdminMode() {
        isAdmin = true;
    }

    public void disableAdminMode() {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "IMPORTANT: the correct usage of a Object(depending on the mode) should be checked by the compiler at compile time. i.e. NOT by a checking a flag." How do you expect to unlock the object then?

Comment: i have the task from a ex teacher and I only tried to translate it into english , i don't know how, so I decided to ask stackoverflow for advice

Comment: Let's assume that we have a read-only object. After unlocking the read-only object, we have got a read-write object. If we update the read-write object, will the changes be available (visible) to the original read-only object?

Comment: yes, changes should be available to the original read-only object

Comment: Good. Is the `unlock` operation valid for all the users or for the administrators only?

Comment: I don't know, the task is incomplete, but in my code everybody is able to unlock the admin operation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ReadOnlyPerson` without setters, `Person extends ReadOnlyPerson`.
Then check via `instanceof` if the object is writable or not.

Comment: Not to mention that you put the setters only in `Person`

Comment: Also, there should be a copy constructor defined for both cases that can up/downgrde the access level.

Answer (score 1):

Let's design the interfaces:

```
interface ReadOnlyPerson {
    String getName();

    double getSalary();
}

interface ReadWritePerson extends ReadOnlyPerson {
    void setName(String name);

    void setSalary(double salary);
}

interface UnlockableReadOnlyPerson extends ReadOnlyPerson {
    ReadWritePerson unlock();
}
```

The implementation will be provided by the factory:

```
final class PersonFactory {
    public static UnlockableReadOnlyPerson create() {
        return new ReadWritePersonImpl();
    }

    private static class ReadWritePersonImpl
        implements UnlockableReadOnlyPerson, ReadWritePerson {

        private String name;
        private double salary;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public double getSalary() {
            return this.salary;
        }

        @Override
        public ReadWritePerson unlock() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void setSalary(final double salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    }
}
```

There are several interesting parts here. Please note them:

1. The return type of the static factory method.
2. The `ReadWritePersonImpl` class implements both the `UnlockableReadOnlyPerson` and `ReadWritePerson` interfaces.
3. The implementation of the `unlock()` method.

Comment: good answer, but ReadWritePerson should probably extend UnlockableReadWritePerson (return this), so you can pass a ReadWritePerson to a method that requires an UnlockablePerson without a cumbersome wrapper.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, this is exactly by design. The `ReadWritePerson` interface must not have the `unlock()` method: there is no need to allow unlocking the already unlocked instance (of the `ReadWritePerson` interface). The interface segregation principle has been followed, so that a convenient interface can be used on the client basis to operate appropriately.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov An unlockable person provides no capabilities that a ReadWritePerson does not, and so any method that operates on an UnlockablePerson should be able to operate on a ReadWritePerson as well.  It is logically a subtype, and the interfaces should reflect that.  Otherwise you're going to have to explain to users why they can't perform such-and-such an operation if their persons are already unlocked.  "How do I re-lock my Persons, then"?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, it feels like you have your own «additional» («re-lock», etc.) vision of the problem and the solution to the problem. Please feel free to share your vision as a separate answer.